# Finding a range of rows and searching for matching column parameters

Tags: python, list, xls, xlrd, xlwt

I have an xls file (>22000 rows) which contains numeric data for each country and each year e.g.:

| country | year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| United States | 1840 | 0 |
| United States | 1841 | 4 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| United States | 2019 | 0 |
| United States | 2020 | 3 |
| Samoa | 1840 | 2 |
| Samoa | 1841 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Samoa | 2019 | 1 |

The task is to find if a country was able to collect the entire range of scores (e.g. 0-6) every year during a specific period of time (e.g. 1900-2020). If the country assumed all of the possible scores from the third column, it gets written in a separate sheet in a xls file. If the country only had 2 or 3 scores from 0-6 range, it won't be included in the file.

The solution I have been able to come up so far is:

```
import xlrd
import xlwt

book = xlrd.open_workbook('book.xls')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

# Create new xls file and two sheets for two criteria
new_book = xlwt.Workbook()
...
new_sheet_2 = new_book.add_sheet('Result - second criterion')

for row in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    country_value = sheet.cell_value(row, 0)
    year_value = sheet.cell_value(row, 3)
    index_value = sheet.cell_value(row, 10)
    ...
    if country_value == sheet.cell_value(row + 1, 0):
       result2.append([row_value, year_value, lex_index])
    ...
```

And that's it. Something tells me that it is not necessary to save data separately in a list, and it's possible to extract necessary countries directly. However, I was unable to find a more appropriate solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found a rather inelegant solution that did work for me. I iterated through the nested list of countries with values and wrote results into a second nested list -- I kept writing until the name of the country changed. Then I checked if the new list contained the values I was looking for. If it did, I wrote them into the final list and emptied the second one for the next country.

```
...
for row in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    row_value = sheet.cell_value(row, 0)
    year_value = sheet.cell_value(row, 3)
    lex_index = sheet.cell_value(row, 10)
...
    if saved_country == row_value:
        result2.append([row_value, year_value, lex_index])
    else:
    if 0.0 in [j for i in result2 for j in i] \
            and 1.0 in [j for i in result2 for j in i] \
            and 2.0 in [j for i in result2 for j in i]\
            and 3.0 in [j for i in result2 for j in i]\
            and 6.0 in [j for i in result2 for j in i]:
        for i in result2:
            result_final.append(i)
    result2.clear()

    saved_country = row_value
    saved_index = lex_index
    saved_year = year_value
```